# ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser() return type?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I try to search users in SharePoint using CSOM. This *does* work

```
ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters queryParams = new ClientPeoplePickerQueryParameters();
queryParams.PrincipalType = PrincipalType.User | PrincipalType.DistributionList;
queryParams.QueryString = "John"

ClientResult<string> clientResult = ClientPeoplePickerWebServiceInterface.ClientPeoplePickerSearchUser(context, queryParams);

context.ExecuteQuery();

dynamic target = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(clientResult.Value);
```

The only thing that bothers me is the `dynamic` part. I simply don't like it and would prefer to cast to the correct type instead.

Any clue, what type could be the right one? The return string looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Key" : "i:0#.w|lsi\\john", 
    "Description" : "LSI\\john", 
    "DisplayText" : "John Doe", 
    "EntityType" : "User", 
    "ProviderDisplayName" : "Active Directory", 
    "ProviderName" : "AD", 
    "IsResolved" : true, 
    "EntityData" : 
    {
      "Title" : "", 
      "MobilePhone" : "", 
      "SIPAddress" : "", 
      "Department" : "", 
      "Email" : "john.doe@contoso.com"
    }, 
    "MultipleMatches" : []
  }
]/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google suggests a `List` of [PickerEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.pickerentity_members(v=office.14).aspx) matches the interface you are describing.

Comment: Not THAT quick. Googled for hours for the method-name without an answer. Thanks, :)